# How to stagger backups

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I have Windows scheduler calling a program that does a full database backup every day at 3:00am.

I would also like to do a transaction log backup every ten minutes.

What is the best way to sync these?

I understand that transaction logs are independent of full back-ups, but is it a problem if the two different tasks both do a backup at 3:00am? i.e. the database is asked to produce a full back-up and a transaction log back-up at exactly the same time.

Perhaps I should have one task and query SQL Server to see if the last full backup was more than 24 hours ago. If not, then do a transaction log backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you're running SQL 2005 or higher, you can run log backups at the same time as a full backup without issue. Glossing over a bit of detail, log backups are based on the last completed full backup at the time that the log backup started. The only time it really matters is when you'd need to do a recovery and even then, it's only ever "contentious" (i.e. "which full backup should I restore given that I want to restore to this point in time?") for log backups that are taken while a full backup is in progress.

If ever you need to do a point-in-time restore for such a time, you'd work backwards. That is, first find the log backup that contains said point in time. Then, to find the full backup that it's based on, look at the database backup lsn for that log backup in either `msdb.dbo.backupset` or by running `restore headeronly` on the log backup. From there, find the full backup that has that value as the checkpoint lsn. Now, you just need to restore *that* full backup (using the `norecovery` option) and every log backup based on it up to and including the log backup you identified in the first step (again, all using `norecovery`). Then run `restore database [yourDB] with recovery` to run crash recovery and you're back in business.

Comment: Sounds fun. I've created a script which looks up the last full backup and, if it is more than 24 hours old, makes a full backup, otherwise it does a transaction backup.

Comment: Ooh… I don't know if I'd be that fancy. That is, if it were me, I'd just start your full backup at the same time every day and run log backups on whatever interval (say every 15 minutes) independently of that. And that is in fact what I *do* do.